# How to extract function parameters with regex and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have the following within the markup of my page:

```
cmCreatePageviewTag("Category: View All Mens (29103)", "29103", null, null, "10151");
```

How can I extract the parameters between the brackets so that I have the following stored in a variable:

```
"Category: View All Mens (29103)", "29103", null, null, "10151"
```

Comment: Where is it within the markup of your page? Why not get it as a string and use `eval`? (That's a horrible idea, but easier than a REGEX unless you do some additional checks before executing the script.)

Comment: This is a very odd requirement. What's the reason you need to do this? There may be a better alternative

Answer (score -1):

```
var regExp = /[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\((.+)\);/;
var str = 'cmCreatePageviewTag("Category: View All Mens (29103)", "29103", null, null, "10151");';

var details = regExp.exec(str);

console.log(details[1]) // "Category: View All Mens (29103)", "29103", null, null, "10151"
```

The regular expression searches for any alphanumeric character or underscore (function name), followed by `(`, followed by any number of characters (the parameters), followed by `);`.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. I have the markup in of the page in a string and I need to extract it from that string